Use a command inside sed
I need some help with my bash script.
I have written a script that greps only ssh rules.
I'm sorry for my English. It's a little difficult to explain.
For example, it should look like this.
FILE:
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2228 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
-A INPUT -s 192.168.30.30/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2228 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2228 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
........ some rules else
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j RATE-LIMIT

Script:
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/path/to/file.txt

IP=`grep -Eiw "2228?" $FILE | grep -Eiw "SSHBRUTE?" | sed "/10.10.10.10/d" `

for name in "$IP"; do
if [ -z "$IP" ] ; then

        do something

    else

        echo "$IP" | sed -e '/192.168.10/s/^/#/g' -e '/192.168.30/s/^/#/g' -i $FILE
fi
done

Put the result in a FILE:
#-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2228 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
#-A INPUT -s 192.168.30.30/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2228 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2228 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j SSHBRUTE
........ some rules else
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j RATE-LIMIT

I want to comment these lines in FILE without FILE re-writing.
Because IP addresses are often in flux in rules so This is also not the correct way to do a change in sed ( sed -e '/192.168.1.1/s/^/#/g' ) etc.
How can I get $IP to be output inside of sed and Saving to a FILE without re-write all lines?
Thanks for help.

See also correct variable capitalization and When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

It's not clear what you're hoping for name in "$IP"; do if [ -z "$IP" ] would do. name can only have 1 value and the loop would only execute 1 time so why loop?

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag and didn't provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output to test with.

If I'm guessing correctly what you mean, you are basically putting the cart before the horse. Instead, write a sed script which leaves the other lines unchanged, and only modifies the ones you want to match.
sed -e '/\<22\>/!b' \
    -e '/\<[Ss][Ss][Hh][Bb][Rr][Uu][Tt][Ee]\>/!b' \
    -e '/IP3/b' -e 's/^/#/' "$FILE" 

In other words, if the current line doesn't match 22, or it doesn't match SSHBRUTE, or if it contains IP3, leave it alone. (! is for "not" and b means "skip the rest of this script for the current input line.")
I'm assuming your sed recognizes \< and \> as word boundaries. If it doesn't, try \b, or [[:<:]] and [[:>:]].
It's unclear what you hoped ? would do here. It seems like purely an error, so I left it out. For the record, 22? makes the second 2 optional, so it matches 2 and 22.
I also left out the -i option. If the results look correct, you can put it back.
For what it's worth, ^ can only match once on each input line, so specifying the g flag on the replacement is completely pointless. See also Command sed using g
Tangentially perhaps see also useless use of grep and Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?

Related to the actual topic of this question, GNU sed (but no other sed I know of) has an /e option which lets you embed a shell command in a substitution. While this can be handy at times, it's rather obscure, and rather inefficient.
I don't see how it could be useful for your problem, anyway.

since this appears to be an iptables config, it would be safer to also check the option preceding to minimise risk of false positives: --dport 22, -j SSHBRUTE, -s (IP1|IP2), etc. If using -E, I believe [[:space:]] / ([[:space:]]|$) is portable instead of \< / \>

Using  GNU sed you could avoid [Ss][Ss][Hh][Bb]... by using \L and hold space: sed  -e 'h;s/.*/\L&/;/\<22\>.*\<sshbrute\>/!{ x;b};x;/\<IP3\>/b;s/^/# /;.
